# Evaluating $\arctan(u)+\arctan(v)+\arctan(w)$, where $u$, $v$, $w$ are the zeros of $P(x) = x^3 - 10x+11$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, complex-numbers, contest-math

I'm trying to understand the solution to the following question, shown below:

> The zeros of the polynomial $P(x) = x^3 - 10x+11$ are $u,v,w$. Determine the value of $\arctan(u)+\arctan(v) +\arctan(w)$.
>
> Note that
> $$\arctan(u) + \arctan(v) + \arctan(w) = \ln (i P(i)) = \ln(11+11i) = \arctan1 = \frac\pi4$$

To justify this further, one can show that
$$Im(\ln(1+ix)) = \arctan x$$ which follows from integrating $\frac{i}{1+ix}$, finding the imaginary part, and noting that $\arctan x = \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$.

I'm not sure how to justify the first equality:

Expanding
$$\arctan(u) + \arctan(v) + \arctan(w) = Im(\ln (1+iu)+\ln (1+iv)+\ln(1+iw))$$ using the identity claimed above, I get $$\arctan(u) + \arctan(v)+\arctan(w) = Im(-i P(i))$$ which doesn't make sense.

Comment: "I get $\arctan(u) + \arctan(v)+\arctan(w) = Im(-i P(i))$" Aren't you forgetting a $\ln$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{multline}
\operatorname{Im}[\ln(1+iu)+\ln(1+iv)+\ln(1+iw)] = \operatorname{Im}[\ln((1+iu)(1+iv)(1+iw))] 
\\= \operatorname{Im}[\ln((-i)^3(i-u)(i-v)(i - w))]= \operatorname{Im}[\ln(iP(i))]
\end{multline}
Their story checks out. Are you sure you didn't make a sign error, like $(1+iu) = i(i-u)$ or $P(x) = (x + u)(x+v)(x+w)$?

Also, complex numbers too complex. Use tangent addition:
\begin{multline}
\tan(\tan^{-1}u + \tan^{-1}v + \tan^{-1}w) = \frac{u + \tan(\tan^{-1}v + \tan^{-1}w)}{1 - u\tan(\tan^{-1}v + \tan^{-1}w)} \\= \frac{u+\frac{v+w}{1-vw}}{1 - \frac{u(v+w)}{1-vw}} = \frac{u+v+w - uvw}{1-(vw+uv+vw)} = \frac{0 -(-11)}{1 - (-10)} = 1
\end{multline}
where the last substitutions come from Vieta's formulas.

Answer (score 0):

By assumption
$$
P(x) = x^3 - 10x+11 = (x-u)(x-v)(x-w)
$$
and this yields
$$
uvw=-11, \, u+v+w=0, \, uv+uw+vw=-10. 
$$

By the intermediate value theorem we may assume that:
$$
1<u<2, \, 2<v<3, \, -4<w<-3.
$$

Hence,
$$
0.7854<\arctan u< 1.1071, \,  1.1071<\arctan v <1.2490, \, -1.3258<\arctan w<-1.2490.
$$

Let $z=\arctan u + \arctan v + \arctan w$. Then $0.5667<z<1.1071$.
By trigonometric identities:
\begin{align*}
\tan z &= \frac{\tan(\arctan u) + \tan(\arctan v + \arctan w)}{1-\tan(\arctan u) \cdot \tan(\arctan v + \arctan w)} \\
   & = \frac{u + \tan(\arctan v + \arctan w)}{1- u \tan(\arctan v + \arctan w)} \\
&= \frac{u + \frac{\tan(\arctan v)+\tan(\arctan w)}{1-\tan(\arctan v)\tan(\arctan w)}}{1- u \frac{\tan(\arctan v)+\tan(\arctan w)}{1-\tan(\arctan v)\tan(\arctan w)}} \\
&= \frac{u + \frac{v+w}{1-vw}}{1- u \frac{v+w}{1-vw}} = \frac{u+v+w-uvw}{1- uv-uw-vw}=\frac{0-(-11)}{1-(-10)}=1.
\end{align*}
The only value of $z$ such that $\tan z =1$ and $0.5667<z<1.1071$ is $\frac\pi4$.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of $x^3 - 10 x + 11$ are real, no complex numbers are needed. The roots are also not large in absolute value, roughly $-3.61, 1.34, 2.27$ The arctangents are about $ -1.3, 0.9, 1.1$ so that sum is between $0$ and $1$

There is a formula for $\tan (x+y); $   let $\tan x = u,  \tan y = v,$   then $\tan(x+y)  = \frac{u+v}{1-uv}.$

If we now let $\tan z = w,$  it turns out
$$  \tan(x+y+z)  = \frac{u+v+w - uvw}{1-vw -wu - uv}  $$  which you can find by expanding $ \tan ((x+y) + z$

Since $u,v,w$   are the roots of $x^3 - 10 x + 11,$  we see that
$$ u+v+w = 0, uv + vw + wu = -10,  uvw = -11. $$

$$  \tan(x+y+z)  = \frac{0 - (-11)}{1-(-10)} = \frac{11}{11} = 1 $$

Thus $ \tan(x+y+z) = 1 $  and
$$ x+y+z = \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5 \pi}{4},  $$   or one of those  added to some multiple of $2 \pi$

NEXT DAY:  do the same thing with: $ \; \; \color{red}{x^3 - 4 x^2 + x + 1} $